# Creating Wearable notifications without the builder?

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

Is it possible to create wearable notifications without using the notification builder?

I already create a notification via new Notification on newer devices and would like to keep that code and still add the Wearable notification to my existing one. Is this possible, or is everything connected to the builder helper class for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`WearableNotifications.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preview/support/wearable/notifications/WearableNotifications.Builder.html) class is only needed if you want to add 'wearable extensions' to your notification. The normal notifications shown by your app are displayed also on the wearable connected to your device without any further integration work.

Comment: If I use my own layout in the normal notification (ie, i dont set the standard id's for title and text, but all is in my own remoteview (works fine locally on the phone). Notifications like that will not show up on the wear emulator. Since I don't want a second local notification just to show the same information on a wear enabled device, is this possible?

Comment: RemoteViews are not supported on the wearable. If you add a title, text, icon to your notification then that is used for the wearable notification while the RemoteView is ignored. On the phone only the RemoteView is displayed and the other properties are ignored.

Comment: This seems to changed with the new SDK, but at the moment still correct.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no WearableNotifications.Builder class anymore in the newest SDK.

But you need to do nothing to simply let your Notification show on Android Wear Devices. 
If you want to have a slightly better look for your Notifications you can use [WearableExtender](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html) to add Android Wear specific actions, pages and layout options.